# Questions about importing google sheets to excel through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I got a request recently asking me to create a button that imports data from google sheets to excel sheets. I have tried the methods found on the internet and made some progress. But the Microsoft documentation about VBA is really vague thus I think it's better to ask the questions here.

I use this piece of the code to import data:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & googleURL, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .WebTables = "1"
    .Refresh False
End With
```

Questions:

1. This piece of the code only imports maximum 100 rows of the data from the google sheet table. Is there a reason or fix to the issue?
2. Is there a way to modify the results so that it doesn't include the column title and row number cells (For example: A, B, 1, 2, 3)? If not is there a way to delete them after the refresh?
3. Is there a way to get a specific cell (For example: D5) from the google sheet and put it on the excel sheet?
4. Is it going to be easier if I read the google sheet and save it in a file first and then modify or read it however I like?

Hope someone can help me and I really appreciate your effort of reading my questions!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a link to test, but I suspect a generic web query will do the job for you. Turn on the Macro recorder and import your spreadsheet data from the web, just like any other, similar, task.

```
Sub Basic_Web_Query()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah4Bis8FTYfCdDJILVdYOG1EZEYtc1N3NF96dHZSYkE&usp=sharing#gid=0", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "q?s=goog_2"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1,2"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```