# Load array with data from google sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've found code that lets me import information into a worksheet from google sheets from this question. [How to import data from Google Sheets into Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562276/how-to-import-data-from-google-sheets-into-excel-with-vba). The code works, but I would like to know how to skip initially loading it into a spreadsheet and put it into an array instead. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the wrong approach for what I was trying to accomplish. The solution was to use an API connector. Here is the relevant code in case anyone needs it in the future.

```
Public Sub getData()
Dim url As String, sheetID As String, queryStr As String, encodedQuery As String, response As String

Dim httpReq As Object
Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

'The sheet identifier from your google sheets link. Look at where I set the url variable to figure out where it is in the link.
sheetID = ""
'https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage
queryStr = "Select *"

encodedQuery = WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(queryStr)

url = "http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" & sheetID & "/gviz/tq?tq=" & encodedQuery

With httpReq
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
End With

Do Until httpReq.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

'The data will come out in JSON format, but this can be resolved with some simple string manipulation.
response = httpReq.responseText
End Sub
```